# Using Typescript with Nodejs - Can't find index.d.ts

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-2017

A friend recommended that I swap over to Typescript from javascript, as a way to deal with the problems I was having implementing promises in loops and conditionals (TS has async/await functionality).  I can never seem to get TS compiling properly.  The latest error I got on the VSCODE terminal (which is different to the set of errors I was getting on the console) was:

```
error TS6053: File 'c:/stuff/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts' not found.
```

So I created that directory structure and put index.d.ts in there and now I am getting these errors:

```
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(6,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(14,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(15,78): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(23,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
```

Comment: The latest versions of Node have async/await.

Comment: ...is that 6.x?

Comment: https://nodejs.org 8.5 is the latest version. Async/Await arrive in version 8.

Comment: Ok. How do I go about updating to that version?  I'm new to node

Comment: I like `n` - it makes switching between versions easy: https://github.com/tj/n

Comment: I don't really need to manage different versions.  The latest will do for me.  Is there a simple upgrade command I can run to get the latest version?

Comment: hey man, try "npm install @types/node"

Comment: It sounds like async/await is available in node 8.x. If that's the case, then I'll use that, as this is the third attempt in three weeks that I've made to try and change over to TS, and every time it's just a wall of errors.  I'm over it.  I just need to work out now how to upgrade to 8.x.  Do you know how?  If so, post an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's not a correct way to solve your problem by doing:

> created that directory structure and put index.d.ts in there

the correct way is installing `@types/node` by npm command in VSCode terminal (MENU: View > Integrated Terminal):

```
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

Before you install it, you'd better delete "@types" folder manually.